# How to rerender functional component using class method, when props are changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a validator class for `<input>` with private variables `error`, `showMessage` and methods `validate` and `isOk`. The intention is to call the `isOk` function from anywhere. So I created a custom functional component for validation, but the problem is that after click to button and trying to check the value, rendering occurs only after changing input. In this case, the component is not re-rendered, but the `validator` props are changed, and the breakpoint is not hit on `ValidatedInput`. It is assumed that the message will be presented immediately. I don't have any ideas. Here is a working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-bash-7g4sz3?file=/src/App.js

```js
export default class Validator {
  #error = "";

  #showMessage = false;

  get error(){
    return this.#error;
  }

  set error(error){
    this.#error = error;  
  }

  get showMessage() {
    return this.#showMessage;
  }

  set showMessage(message) {
    this.#showMessage = message;
  }

  validate = (value) => {
    //there should be some logic here, but we need to show an error
    this.#error = "ERROR " + value;
    //this.#error = '';
    return this.#error;
  };

  isOk = () => {
    this.#showMessage = true;
    return this.#error.length === 0 || this.#error ==='';
  };
}

export const ValidatedInput = (props) => {
  const { value, validator, onChange, ...otherProps } = props;
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");
  const [showMessage, setShowMessage] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (validator) {
      const error = validator.validate(value);
      setErrorMessage(error);
      setShowMessage(validator.showMessage);
    }
  }, [value, validator]);

  return (
    <>
      <input
        {...otherProps}
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => {
          onChange(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      {showMessage && <label>{errorMessage}</label>}
    </>
  );
};

export const ValidatedInputDemo = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [validator] = useState(new Validator());
  return (
    <>
      <ValidatedInput
        value={value}
        validator={validator}
        onChange={(e) => setValue(e)}
      />
      <br />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          validator.isOk() ? alert("OK") : alert("BAD");
        }}
      >
        Check
      </button>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just added the `showMessage` property changed by the state ¯_(ツ)_/¯

```js
export const ValidatedInput = (props) => {
  const { value, validator, onChange, showMessage, ...otherProps } = props;
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (validator) {
      const error = validator.validate(value);
      setErrorMessage(error);
    }
  });

  return (
    <>
      <input
        {...otherProps}
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => {
          onChange(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      {showMessage && <label>{errorMessage}</label>}
    </>
  );
};

export const ValidatedInputDemo = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [validator] = useState(new Validator());
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      <ValidatedInput
        value={value}
        validator={validator}
        showMessage={show}
        onChange={(e) => setValue(e)}
      />
      <br />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setShow(true);
          validator.isOk() ? alert("OK") : alert("BAD");
        }}
      >
        Check
      </button>
    </>
  );
};
```